# Names of objects in a list?

Tags: python, list, introspection

I'm trying to iteratively write dictionaries to file, but am having issues creating the unique filenames for each dict.

```
def variable_to_value(value):
    for n, v in globals().items():
        if v == value:
            return n
    else: 
        return None

a = {'a': [1,2,3]}
b = {'b': [4,5,6]}
c = {'c': [7,8,9]}

for obj in [a, b, c]:
    name = variable_to_value(obj)
    print(name)
```

This prints:

```
a
obj
obj
```

How can I access the name of the original object itself instead of `obj`?

Comment: I'm confused  how `a` is printed

Comment: What do you mean when you say "name of the object"? What will you expect to see?

Comment: @cricket_007 Probably because the ordering of `dict.items` is undefined, and `variable_to_value` returns the name of the first matching variable it finds.  On my system, I get `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `obj`, your iteration variable is also in `globals`. Whether you get `a` or `obj` is just by luck. You can't solve the problem in general because an object can have any number of assignments in globals. You could update your code to exclude known references, but that is very fragile.

For example

```
a = {'a': [1,2,3]}
b = {'b': [4,5,6]}
c = {'c': [7,8,9]}

print("'obj' is also in globals")

def variable_to_value(value):
    return [n for n,v in globals().items() if v == value]

for obj in [a, b, c]:
    name = variable_to_value(obj)
    print(name)

print("you can update your code to exclude it")

def variable_to_value(value, exclude=None):
    return [n for n,v in globals().items() if v == value and n != exclude]

for obj in [a, b, c]:
    name = variable_to_value(obj, 'obj')
    print(name)

print("but you'll still see other assignments")

foo = a
bar = b
bax = c

for obj in [a, b, c]:
    name = variable_to_value(obj, 'obj')
    print(name)
```

When run

```
'obj' is also in globals
['a', 'obj']
['b', 'obj']
['c', 'obj']
you can update your code to exclude it
['a']
['b']
['c']
but you'll still see other assignments
['a', 'foo']
['b', 'bar']
['c', 'bax']
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns the first name it finds referencing an object in your `globals()`. However, at each iteration, the name `obj` will reference each of the objects. So either the name `a`, `b` or `c` is returned or `obj`, depending on the one which was reached first in `globals()`.

You can avoid returning `obj` by excluding that name from the search in your function - *sort of hackish*:

```
def variable_to_value(value):
    for n, v in globals().items():
        if v == value and n != 'obj':
            return n
    else: 
        return None
```

Comment: This makes the outcome of the function depend on what calls it. (E.g. it won't work if the OP's look had used "my_obj" as the iteration name instead of "obj".) That's not how functions should work.

Comment: @acdr It is clearly stated as an *hackish approach*. One should hardly be fiddling with names in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't actually work like this.

Objects in Python don't have innate names. It's the names that belong to an object, not the other way around: an object can have many names (or no names at all).

You're getting two copies of "obj" printed, because at the time you call `variable_to_value`, both the name `b` and the name `obj` refer to the same object! (The dictionary `{'b': [4,5,6]}`) So when you search for the global namespace for any value which is equal to `obj` (note that you should be checking using `is` rather than `==`) it's effectively random whether or not you get `b` or `obj`.

Comment: Side question: why use `is` instead of `==`?

Comment: `==` checks for equivalence, not identity. E.g. `a = 1000`, `b=1000`, `a==b` returns `True`, but `a is b` returns False. They're not the same object, they're just equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the name of any object available in the `globals()`?

Inside the `for` loop, `globals() dict` is being mutated, adding `obj` in its namespace. So on your second pass, you have two references to the same object (originally only referenced by the name 'a').

Danger of using `globals()`, I suppose.